# Heroku Ignoring runtime.txt file

Tags: python, git, heroku

My flask app runs locally.

When I push it to Heroku via `git push heroku master`, I get the following error:

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.20.0 (from -r /tmp/build_b6c59d74/requirements.txt (line 12))
```

I believe this is because my local python version does not match Heroku’s.

When I run `python -V` I get `Python 3.7.4`.

As per the full logs below, Heroku is using the current default of `python-3.6.12`.

As per [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes), I added a `runtime.txt` file to my root directory (the same directory as my `requirements.txt` file).

I initially added `python-3.7.4`, but after checking Heroku’s [supported runtimes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes), it seems I should be using `python-3.7.9`.

I've updated it to `python-3.7.9`.

When I run `cat runtime.txt`, I get `python-3.7.9`.

I've checked that there are no line breaks, spaces and that I'm using the right dash.

But when I run `git push Heroku master`, it seems to be ignoring `runtime.txt` and installing `python-3.6.12` (see full logs below).

I've checked that I'm running a [supported stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#stack-support-details), and when I run `heroku stack` it shows `heroku-20`.

`heroku buildpacks` returns `heroku/python/.

Below are the full logs of the error returned when I run `git push heroku master`

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting alembic==1.5.3
remote:          Downloading alembic-1.5.3.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting click==7.1.2
remote:          Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask==1.1.2
remote:          Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-Migrate==2.6.0
remote:          Downloading Flask_Migrate-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
remote:          Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-WTF==0.14.3
remote:          Downloading Flask_WTF-0.14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.11.2
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
remote:        Collecting Mako==1.1.4
remote:          Downloading Mako-1.1.4.tar.gz (479 kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.20.0 (from -r /tmp/build_b6c59d74/requirements.txt (line 12)) (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0b3, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2rc1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.20.0 (from -r /tmp/build_b6c59d74/requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: dd64a89ce1402daf7c7b0804558f3f6ec776d188
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version dd64a89ce1402daf7c7b0804558f3f6ec776d188
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to pure-lowlands-59273.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/pure-lowlands-59273.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pure-lowlands-59273.git'
```

Note that I believe the warning above is unrelated and is instead due to me trying to push to Heroku multiple times.

I checked https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version and this does not seem to be the issue. All local changes are committed and the branch is correct (both on the `master` branch).

This seemingly simple process is really making me question my sanity.

I can't find anything online above people reporting similar errors, so I'm presuming it's some kind of typo?

I checked the spelling of `runtime.txt` 17 times and its file contents for extra spaces or line breaks. No dice.

I'd love some help on this. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: Are you sure you committed your `runtime.txt` file? Numpy 1.20.0 drops support for Python 3.6, so another option would be to downgrade your numpy version to 1.19.

Comment: Does your requirements.txt contains a line with numpy?

Comment: Yes `numpy==1.20.0` is in my `requirements.txt` file.

Right, so it definitely seems like Python 3.6 on Heroku is the issue.

I've run `git add .` and `git commit -m "No changes made"` more times than I can count. `git status` shows there is nothing to commit. 

While I can definitely revert this to `1.19`, I'd love to get to the bottom of this.

These are very useful comments; thank you Mihai and squeezer.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what the issue was.

After updating `numpy==1.19.5` in my `requirements.txt` file, the same error was returned as it was attempting to download `numpy==1.20.0`

At this point, [Mihai’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9374673/mihai-chelaru) comment was looking very likely—this is a commit issue.

I re-read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version and noticed the following notice:

> Following changes in the industry, Heroku has updated our default git branch name to main. If the project you’re deploying uses master as its default branch name, use git push heroku master.

I noticed in my notes I had `git push heroku master` as the way to deploy changes to Heroku. So maybe somewhere along the way, I did something funky with git and pushed to the wrong branch.

I found this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-branches on Migrating from Master -> Main.

So I ran:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b main
git push heroku main
```

Bang... straight to `python-3.7.9`.

Thank you all for your help!

I hope this explanation stops someone from making the same mistake in the future :)

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue and your solution worked for me.

Comment: No problem JGV. It’s quite an annoying issue. I messaged Heroku support and asked them to keep consistent in their docs in calling their head branch `master` or `main`. Their documentation is inconsistent. Obviously it's my fault for not paying enough attention to what I was reading—but this might help prevent others experiencing this same issue.